# Angular2: how do i navigate to children from component.ts

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am on homepage /home and want to navigate to children /unitsheet

normally we write this.route.navigate(['home']); but how do i write it from children to get path as localhost:4200/home/unitsheet

```js
const ROUTER_DATA: Routes = [
    { path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path:'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
        { path:'unitsheet', component: unitComponent},
    ]},
    { path:'', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate('unitsheet')
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="'unitsheet'">unitsheet</a>
```

or you can use absolute paths

```
<a [routerLink]="'/home/unitsheet'">unitsheet</a>
```

Comment: I think other one don't need `[]` wrapper, as its a simple `string`(we don't want to evaluate them)

Comment: You are right, `[]` is not needed for plain string values. I think it's good practice to use them anyway because otherwise it will be added to the DOM as attribute which is useless and bloats the DOM unnecessarily. I myself often pointed out that `[]` is not actually necessary.

Comment: but this guy `[routerLink]="/home/unitsheet"` will throw an error AFAIK, as parser will try to evaluate `/home/unitsheet` as expression(isn't valid expression, correct?).

Comment: You are right again. Seems I'm not fully awake yet :-[

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I'm always eager to get my mistakes pointed out to improve my knowledge and don't get lazy ;-)